Porting TimesNet from PyTorch to Tensorflow.js
I want to use part of the Time Series Library, namely TimesNet on Tensorflow.js. How can I do this?
This requires knowledge of PyTorch, Python and mathematics.
Source code https://github.com/thuml/Time-Series-Library/blob/main/models/TimesNet.py
Tutorial https://github.com/thuml/Time-Series-Library/blob/main/tutorial/TimesNet_tutorial.ipynb
My request is more suited to a request for help with porting implementation. Partial advice won't help me much.
I carefully studied the source code, some are clear, some are not. And it will take me a lot of time to learn the features of Python and PyTorch.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Have you tried convert the model to tflite format? There are some tutorial online show how to convert from pytorch model to tflite.

@MinhNH no, I didn't try because I want to create my own models without using python in the future
